# finite p-group subgroup of infinite p-group

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups

is there any finite p-group G that is subgroup or minimal/maximal subgroup of infinite p-group H?
if yes what is the limits? can this happen with different p's?
i'm more interested in being maximal subgroup of infinite p-group

Comment: Tarski Monsters have maximal (and minimal) subgroups of order $p$ and are infinite, and exist for all sufficiently large prime $p$.

Comment: So a question that springs to mind is whether, for example, a finite $2$-group can be a maximal subgroup of an infinite $2$-group.